# problem with "select new Object ... join ... where"

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm having a problem with an HQL query

Three classes

ClassOne is my BusinessObject

```
public class ClassOne {  
  private int id;  
  private int status;
  private Set<ClassTwo> classTwos;  
  + other fields/getters/setters/constructor etc  
}
```

ClassTwo is referenced in a set of ClassOne and is kind of the history of an object of ClassOne

```
public class ClassTwo {  
  private int id;  
  private int oldStatus;  
  private int newStatus;  
  private String message;  
  //+ getters/setters/constructor etc  
}
```

ClassThree is my DTO/VO with just one classTwo (not the whole history)

```
public class ClassThree {  
  private int id;  
  private int status;  
  private ClassTwo classTwo;  
  public ClassThree(int pId, int pStatus, ClassTwo pClassTwo) {  
    id=pId;  
    status=pStatus;  
    classTwo=pClassTwo;   
  }
  //+ getters/setters etc
}
```

Now I'd like to create an HQL query like this:
I'd like to get all objects of ClassThree with a certain status and if it exists the newest ClassTwo with a certain newStatus.
For example:
I'd like to get all the DTOs (ClassThree) of ClassOne whose status is now 1, but earlier in their history it has been 2 and I'd like to have the latest ClassTwo object which has 2 as newStatus.

```
SELECT new ClassThree(c1.id, c1.status, c2)  
FROM ClassOne c1  
LEFT JOIN c1.classtwos c2 (...)
```

and (...) is where I don't know what to do, I'm not even sure if it's a join / join fetch

Looked around and tried quite a lot already, but no clue. Especially with the join fetch I get some Hibernate errors like `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list`.

Fetching the BusinessObject like that is no problem

```
SELECT distinct(c1)
FROM ClassOne c1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH c1.classtwos c2
```

and I get the ClassTwos as my field.

Thanks in advance,
Jacob

P.S.: One thing might be important, ClassTwo has no reference to ClassOne!!

P.P.S : The simple SQL query which resolves my problem looks more or less like that:

```
select * from classone as c1 left join (select * from classtwo where newstatus = 2) c2 on c1.id=c2.id_classone whete c1.status = 1
```

This query works and gets all the information needed on my PostGreSQL DB, but I'd really like to have an HQL to continue to work with, especially for maintenance reasons and so on...

**Update with workaround solution:**

Getting the ids of all the ClassOnes with a status 1

```
Collection<Integer> ids = null;
ids = (Collection<Integer>) getHibernateTemplate().execute(
  new HibernateCallback() {
    public Object doInHibernate(Session pSession) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      return getDocumentIds(pSession, pStatus);
    }
  }
);
```

Now I get all the DTOs which have been in status 2 (thanks to Ivan) with:

Named query *Document.dto.with.transfer*

```
SELECT new DocumentDTO(d.id, d.status, histo)
FROM Document d
LEFT JOIN d.histories histo
WHERE 
  d.id in (:ids)
AND
  (histo.id = 
    SELECT MAX(innerhisto.id) 
    FROM Document innerd 
    JOIN innerd.histories innerhisto
    WHERE d.id = innerd.id AND innerhisto.newStatus = 21)
```

(in my code I use some named queries)

```
List<DocumentDTO> lRes = new ArrayList<DocumentDTO>();
Query lQuery = getSession(false).getNamedQuery("Document.dto.with.transfer");
lQuery.setParameterList("ids", ids);
lResultList.addAll(lQuery.list());
```

afterwards I remove all the IDs already found from my list ids

```
for (DocumentDTO dto : lResultList) {
  ids.remove(dto .getId());
}
```

I do a third query using a second constructor for the DTO, initializing my history with a dummy-object.

Named query *Document.dto.simple*

```
SELECT new DocumentDTO(d.id, d.status)
FROM Document d
WHERE 
  d.id in (:ids)
```

(another named query)

```
lQuery = getSession(false).getNamedQuery("Document.dto.simple");
lQuery.setParameterList("ids", ids);
lResultList.addAll(lQuery.list());
```

and it's done.

Comment: You're using Java and NHibernate together?  I thought NHibernate was for .NET?

Comment: No, just tagged wrong, in fact its Java + Hibernate

Comment: I don't understand the criteria to retrieve a unique c2 from your description.

Comment: I just wan't to get one specific c2, because there is only one which might be interesting for me.  
Real world example:  
ClassOne is a document, with status the last action performed on the document (read, write, moved, etc).  
ClassTwo the history of a document (read, write access, moved, etc).  
I want to have the message and the previous status of the last write access (but only if it exists) on the document along with my document and it's current status in ClassThree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include Documents with no history we should use `LEFT JOIN` and test for empty collection, then we use subquery (`SELECT COUNT(...)`) to detect all documents that have never been in status 2. The last `OR-clause` is for fetching the last history with the specified status.

Here is the HQL query:

```
SELECT new DocumentDto(doc.id, doc.status, hist) 
FROM Document doc 
LEFT JOIN doc.histories hist 
WHERE doc.status = :docStatus 
AND (size(doc.histories) = 0 
OR (SELECT COUNT(innerhist) 
    FROM Document innerdoc JOIN innerdoc.histories innerhist 
    WHERE innerdoc.id=doc.id AND innerhist.newStatus = :historyStatus) = 0
OR (hist.newStatus = :historyStatus AND hist.id = 
    (SELECT max(innerhist.id) 
     FROM Document innerdoc 
     JOIN innerdoc.histories innerhist 
     WHERE innerdoc.status = :docStatus AND innerhist.newStatus = :historyStatus))
```

Then call `setParameter("historyStatus", 2)` and `setParameter("docStatus", 1)` on your query to get the correct result.

That's it!

Please note, I've made an assumption, that we can use a value of `id` attribute of `History` as an indicator of the order in which objects were put in your database.

Comment: Your assumption on the id is right. but the query only extracts the ClassThrees if an a ClassTwo object with newStatus = 2 exists.
The thing I need is rather like the SQL query I added to the question.

Comment: Ivan, the updated HQL returns every hist entry with status = 2 instead of just the last one.

Comment: @Tomislav I know. But this HQL corresponds to SQL provided by jacob in the last update.

Comment: @Ivan, you're right about the sql, but it was more or less ment to give an example of what I want, like Tomislav said, I really want only the last one. This query return on DTO for every history-entry of status = 2

Comment: @Ivan, just one little problem (or rather large) left. It only fetches the DTOs which were at least once in status 2, but the thing I'm looking for is: I'd like to have all the DTO's in status one with nothing as history if they were never in status 2 and with their last history with status 2 if the DTO has been in the status 2 before. Thanks a lot up to now!

Comment: @Ivan, I'm sorry but it's still not it. Imagine, I have a document in status 1, it changes to status 3 and back to 1. I would have two history entries, one which tells me change from 1 to three, the second 3 to 1. My document was NEVER in status 2 but IS in status 1 and HAS a history. So I would like to have it appearing in my results. Your last update only gives me documents which never changed and documents with no history.

Comment: @jacob, is it a must to retrieve all your objects in one query?

Comment: @Ivan, no not really, just thought it would be nice.

Comment: @Ivan and the others. Thanks a lot for your help. I'll modify my question to show how I finally managed to solve the problem with you help. If you have any other suggestions, don't hesitate

Comment: @jacob, I've just added the last condition to the query :)

Comment: I'll give it a try, otherwise I found a way to get all what I want. I'll post after testing.

Comment: Still having a problem :). Now, back to one of the first ones. For every document, which has never been in status 2, but has history entries, the query creates on DTO for every history entry. The rest is fine, for every Document with at least one history entry status 2 it creates one DTO, and for no history entry too.

Comment: @jacob, I see. Probably, this issue couldn't be avoided, because we use JOIN. So, I would suggest to split this query into two - the first one will select Docs with no history and no histories with newstatus = 2, the second one - Docs with the latest histor with newstatus = 2. If you need assistance, let me know.